# Can Hybrid Mobile Apps built using HTML5 interact with a server and database?

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been looking for an answer to this question. And I can not find any clear explanation anywhere on the web. It is really frustrating.

Can I make an HTML5 Mobile app consume an API on a remote server ?

If yes, then how is it achieved ?

Do frameworks like cordova and ionic support it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is achievable in cordova and ionic, Use any scripting language to access API on remote server.

Here is some code that I use for making connections to a REST style API (uses jquery):

```
var api = {
    connection: {
        baseUrl: 'your_domain.tld',
        apiUrl: '/some_path/'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        api.setupAjaxDefaults();
    },
    setupAjaxDefaults: function() {
        var headers = {
            'Accept': "application/json; encoding='utf-8'",
            'Content-Type': "application/json; encoding='utf-8'"
        };
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: headers,
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true
        });
    },
    testCall: function(data) {
        api.ajaxGet( someMethod, data, aSuccessCallback, anErrorCallback );
    },
    ajaxGet: function(methodName, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: api.connection.baseUrl + api.connection.apiUrl + methodName,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result, status, xhr) {
                if ($.isFunction(successCallback)) {
                    successCallback(result);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                if ($.isFunction(errorCallback)) {
                    errorCallback();
                }
            }

        });
    },
    ajaxGetCached: function(methodName, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: api.connection.baseUrl + api.connection.apiUrl + methodName,
            data: data,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result, status, xhr) {
                if ($.isFunction(successCallback)) {
                    successCallback(result);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                if ($.isFunction(errorCallback)) {
                    errorCallback();
                }
            }

        });
    }
};
```

To use this, You first call `api.initialize();`

Then to make a call (example of testCall in place above):

```
api.testCall(someApiMethod, { data: someData, moreData: evenMore });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Because Ionic also supports javascript, you can just send HTML requests to an external api using javascript.

Comment: So literally there are no limits?

Comment: You are probably limited by the data usage, as you don't want your app to use a lot of bandwith. But for example getting information of the weather using a php api that returns json, yes this is possible.

Comment: Can I push notifications from server to the app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you have knowledge of Angular JS then you can call any api using $http. Else you can call api using Ajax in normal javascript.

**IONIC :**

```
$http.get('URL').then(function(resp) {
    console.log('Success', response);
    // For JSON responses, response.data contains the result
  }, function(err) {
    console.error('ERR', error);
    // error.status will contain the status code
  })
```